I need to fix the bibliography and possibility to use \cite
I have the bibliography but I can't use \cite[]{key}. It doesn't work at all. I can see only letters from the key (not the link)
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{MA} M.Adachi, \emph{Embedding and Immersions}, American Mathematical Society, 1984.
\bibitem{AW} A. Wasserman, \emph{The Atiyah-Singer Index Theorem}, online LENT, 2010.
\bibitem{E} R.Engelking, \emph{Topologia ogólna}, PWN, Warszawa, 2007.
\bibitem{MJ} J.Milnor, \emph{Lectures on the h-cobordism theorem}, Princeton University Press, 1993.
\bibitem{MP} M.Persson, \emph{The Whitney embedding theorem}, UMEA University, 2014.
\bibitem{JL} J.Lawson, \emph{Differential Geometry}, Louisiana State University, 2006, \url{https://www.math.lsu.edu/~lawson/Chapter1.pdf}
\bibitem{MG} M.Gualtieri, \emph{Topology 1, Smooth manifolds}, University of Toronto, 2016, \url{http://www.math.toronto.edu/mgualt/courses/MAT1300F-2016/}
\bibitem{SL} S.Lu, \emph{Isometric Embedding of Riemannian manifolds}, 2012.
\bibitem{MZ} M.Zakrzewski, \emph{Notatki do seminarium dyplomowego}.
\end{thebibliography}

\begin{defn}\label{Rozmaitość topologiczna}\cite{M} - I will see in this particular case: Rozmaitość topologiczna M. This `M` is not a link

Macroses: ```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{mwrep} %do druku dwustronnego proszę dodać twoside
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{jpg/}{png/}}
%\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}



% otoczenia dla twierdzeń
\newtheorem{tw}{Twierdzenie}[chapter]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemat}[chapter]
\newtheorem{wns}[tw]{Wniosek}


% otoczenia dla definicji i przykładów
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{przkl}{Przykład}[chapter]
\newtheorem{defn}[tw]{Definicja}

% otoczenie dla uwagi
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{uwg}[tw]{Uwaga}


% definicje zbiorów liczbowych
\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}% liczby rzeczywiste
\def\NN{\mathbb{N}}% liczny naturalne
\def\CC{\mathbb{C}}% liczby zespolone
\def\QQ{\mathbb{Q}}% liczny wymierne

%zbiór pusty
\usepackage{amssymb}

\let\oldemptyset\emptyset
\let\emptyset\varnothing


\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    sortlocale=pl_PL,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}

\begin{document}
\baselineskip18pt
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}




Please provide a minimal working example (compilable Tex file) so that we can get a clearer idea what exactly you are doing.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Did you write the bibliography by hand, or did you use BibTeX/BibLaTeX? If you wrote it by hand, do you have a reason to do so?

Also I'm having trouble reproducing the issue. When I add \documentclass{article} \usepackage{hyperref} \begin{document} \cite{MJ} in front of your bibliography and \end{document} after then I get a normal citation [4] as output which is a working hyperlink to the Milnor reference.

The compilation is going without issues. When I use \cite[page 1]{MZ} I only can see MZ and it doesn't work as a link. I will add screenshots to the question

I think more context is needed following the edit, where is the defn environment defined? \label{Rozmaitość topologiczna} wouldn't normally print its argument, and \cite{M} would print [?] as your bibliography shown has no entry with key M. There's something going on in your document that's missing in the question, a short but compilable document would help a lot.

I see, Yes the example maybe not be correct. I try to use the correct keys. Also I updated the post with my presets

don't post disconnected fragments that we can not test, post a small self contained complete document that shows the problem, renove all packages that are not related to your question

biblatex is incompatible with a manual \begin{thebibliography} environment, either remove the package or use biber to generate a bibliography, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5105/106162 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/106162

you are loading biblatex but have a hand written bibliography so you are not using biblatex at all.

Yes, I removed biblatex and it works)  Thanks guys!
